# Google Forms apps script: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Processor Name')

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple Google Form that grabs information from a user and
based on that information I want to decide who gets the email. For
some reasons Google Apps Script keeps returning undefined error.

[image]

```
  function sendEmail(e) {
  var named_values = e.namedValues
  var processor = named_values["Processor Name"]


  console.log("named_values::", named_values)
  console.log("values::", processor)
}
```

Comment: Try `e.namedValues["Processor Name"][0]`

Comment: e.namedValues is part of the form submit event object for a linked spreadsheet

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your form responses to have an idea of their structure?

Comment: @Cooper I am literally not getting anything returned in event object (e) itself. Not sure what am I doing wrong here..

Comment: @FernandoLara Responses are in following order Timestamp, Reference ID, Date of Incident, Processor Name, Legal Name of Farm

Comment: Did you create the trigger?

Comment: @Cooper Yes I did. It is getting triggered but nothing is returned for event object

Comment: There is two onFormSubmit triggers one is for the form and one is for the spreadsheet

Comment: @Cooper I am using the one for the form.

Comment: The one for the form does not have values or namedValues

Comment: You are totally right. Are you planning to post this as an answer? @Cooper ?

Comment: @FernandoLara nope

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

As mentioned by [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) the problem is that the script is bounded to a Google Form, therefore the Form submit event object does not contain `namedValues` on it.

According to Google's documentation, `namedValues` only exists in the event object that is retrieved from the Form submit trigger when the script is bound to a Google Sheet.

#### References:

- [Google Sheet events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)
- [Google Form events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events)